# Does mlogit require a specific kind of row name?

Tags: r, mlogit

I have data which looks like this:

```
## # A tibble: 6 x 7
##   sampleno    h0    h1    h2    h3    h4 correct_hyp_no
##<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl><dbl>
## 1 0  7498  7147  7137  7003  7003 0
## 2 1  7349  7133  7104  7065  6960 0
## 3 2  6907  6676  6671  6575  6575 0
## 4 3  7339  7267  7133  7089  7051 0
## 5 4  5378  5316  5248  5205  5171 NA
## 6 5  7411  7253  7233  7137  7118 4
```

When I run

```
mlogit(correct_hyp_no ~ h0 + h1 + h2 + h3 + h4, my_data)
```

I get an error

> Error in data.frame(lapply(index, function(x) x[drop = TRUE]),
>   row.names = rownames(mydata)) :    row names supplied are of the wrong
>   length

I'm fairly new to R. I didn't explicitly name rows, but it looks like it's automatically picked up 1,2,3,4,5,6 as names. What's going wrong, please?

Comment: Your example is not self-contained, so we cannot help. Maybe wrapping "my_data" into `as.data.frame()` might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reputation is too low to comment, but like Michael M said, you have not provided a reproducible example. That said, there are a few things you can do to get going.

1. The data would need to be transformed into a format that `mlogit` can understand. Your data appears to be in wide format, so you would want to transform it to long format. See `?mlogit.data`.
2. Transforming the data will take care of the outcome variable, which will be coded as a TRUE/FALSE. However, it will probably be necessary to drop the situations where no outcome was recorde, i.e. where `correct_hyp_no == NA`.

If setting up the data correctly does not work, please provide a reproducible MWE and more information about what it is that you are trying to do.